# Do I need to add nil check after decoding a pointer value with the json package?

Tags: json, go, null

I have been writing in Go for a long time and recently while rewriting the code I came across a strange thing. I did a couple of tests and `if request == nil` check never worked. Previously, I was always afraid of getting a `nil` pointer exception, and so I inserted checks everywhere. But in this case, the `json` decode error handler seems to cover all cases.

```
    var (
        request *models.Owner
        err     error
    )

    err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&request)
    if err != nil {
        render.Render(w, r, response.ErrInvalidRequest(err))
        return
    }

    if request == nil {
        render.Render(w, r, response.ErrInvalidRequest("request is nil"))
        return
    }
```

`if request == nil` is it possible to catch this? Perhaps this check is unnecessary, and if I remove this check in my project, the code will become cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that `nil` error will be returned and `request` will still be `nil`, but only if the input JSON is the JSON `null` value.

For example:

```
type Owners struct {
    Name string
}

var request *Owners

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("null"), &request); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(request == nil)
fmt.Println(request)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vOpB1-llwGz)):

```
true
<nil>
```

This is documented at [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal):

> **To unmarshal JSON into a pointer, Unmarshal first handles the case of the JSON being the JSON literal null. In that case, Unmarshal sets the pointer to nil.** Otherwise, Unmarshal unmarshals the JSON into the value pointed at by the pointer. If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new value for it to point to.